# wsdl java class case sensitivity

Tags: java, wsdl, wsdl2java, xfire

In the wsdl I have 2 types, same name, different cases: LoginResponse and LOGINRESPONSE.

If I use xfire to generate the java classes, it only generates one class, LoginResponse,
discarding the LOGINRESPONSE.

How do I get around this?

```
<s:element name="LoginResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LoginResult" type="tns:LOGINRESPONSE" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

  <s:complexType name="LOGINRESPONSE">
    <s:attribute name="Message" type="s:string" />
    <s:attribute name="Token" type="s:string" />
    <s:attribute name="DataFormat" type="s:string" />
    <s:attribute name="Header" type="s:boolean" use="required" />
    <s:attribute name="Suffix" type="s:boolean" use="required" />
  </s:complexType>
```

Comment: This may be some defect with "xfire". 
But you can avoid same by having completely different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names declared in WSDL are indeed case sensitive, and it is *legal* to use names that differ only in their case.  However, it has to be a bad idea:

- Surely, it is a bad idea from the perspective of readability.  (I mean, if you were writing a Java program you wouldn't declare variables `acat` and `aCat` in the same namespace.  Would you?)
- While WSDL is case sensitive, programming language bindings will need to map WSDL names to case insensitive program identifiers (e.g. in Visual Basic I believe), or they may case mangle them so that the generated identifiers conform to the programming language's style conventions.  In either case, WSDL names that differ only in letter case can lead to problems.

IMO the best long term fix for your problem is to change the WSDL so that you don't have elements, types, etc whose names differ only by case.

Comment: The wsdl is out of my control. However I can save the wsdl as a local file, modify that file manually, and then generate java classes from it. It's not ideal, but it is enough for now.